# Limit of infinite series - Partial Sums

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Lets say that I have got the following partial sum of a infinite series:

> $$
> \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}
> $$

I learnt that if $A$ is a partial sum and its limit is $\lambda$ and $B$ is also a partial sum and its limit is $\beta$ then the limit of $\frac AB$ is *$\frac\lambda\beta$*. So far so good.

Now, I would like to propose an example:

$$\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n} $$

If we evaluate the limit of the numerator, it goes towards $+\infty$, right? I mean, as $N \rightarrow \infty$, the series $5^n-3^{n-1}$ diverges for infinity too.

Now, if we evaluate the denominator $5^n+3^n$ it also approaches infinity as N gets bigger.

So by intuition I would say that the limit of $\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}$  is also $\infty$, because $\frac∞∞$ should be infinity, right? Although something tells me it is not defined. Turns out that it is wrong to say though, because if you plot this "rational" function on a Cartesian plane, you will see that as N (Number of terms) approaches ∞, the partial sum approaches 1. Why is that?

Thanks in advance, it is really blowing my mind.

This example comes from this exercise:

[image]

Comment: $\frac{\infty}{\infty} \ne \infty.$ Consider $\frac xx$. As $x\rightarrow \infty$ , both the numerator and denominator approaches to $\infty$ , but the limit is always $1.$

Comment: There seems to be much confusion of the terminology here. I see you keep mentioning "partial sums". Are you really asking $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}$ or $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}$? $\{\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}\}$ is a *sequence*, not a *series*.

Comment: I mean: $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$

Comment: @MatheusMinguini You could type `$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$` for $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$.

Comment: Sorry, jack. I was having trouble editing the expression. If you could read my below answer, I think that is the core of my doubts. Thanks for your time

Comment: @MatheusMinguini: thanks for your message. Could you check my edit of your post? Is that the limit you are looking for?

Comment: That is it, Jack! Thank you. That is what I am looking for

Comment: "I learnt that if $A$ is a partial sum and its limit is $\lambda$ and $B$ is also a partial sum and its limit is $\beta$ then the limit of $\frac AB$ is *$\frac\lambda\beta$*." - This doesn't apply here. You don't have a quotient of partial sums, you have a partial sum of quotients.

Answer (score 3):

> How to evaluate $\displaystyle
> \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}
> $?

First of all, 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}\neq \frac{ \sum_{n=1}^N 5^n-3^{n-1}}{\sum_{n=1}^N 5^n+3^n}.
$$
In general, $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{p_n}{q_n}\neq \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N p_n}{\sum_{q=1}^N q_n}$.

Now, let $a_n=\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}$. A necessary condition for $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$ exists is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

However, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}\neq0
$$

Thus $\displaystyle
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}
$ does not exist.

---

[Added:] The above is an answer to [your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452013/limit-of-infinite-series-partial-sums/3452052?noredirect=1#comment7095916_3452013) in the post. According to your new comments below and what you added, you have asked an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What your really want to evaluate is the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}.
$$

There is **no** partial sum here, although this problem *could* be phrased as a limit of partial sum of a series. This is nothing but the limit of a **sequence** of real numbers and you should not call this as "partial sum".

> So by intuition I would say that the limit of $\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}$  is also $\infty$, because $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ should be infinity, right?

[Not even wrong.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) The symbol $\infty$ is **not** a real number and the expression $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is **not** a fraction of two real numbers. Beginners in calculus should strictly follow definitions regarding any statements containing the symbol $\infty$ or the word "infinite". Consider the following two examples:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{n}=2,\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi n}{n}=\pi.
$$
It does not makes sense to say that $\frac{\infty}{\infty}=2$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}=\pi$.

> ... if you plot this "rational" function on a Cartesian plane, you will see that as <s>N (Number of terms)</s> $n$ approaches $\infty$, the <s>partial sum</s> **sequence** approaches $1$.

This gives you the "correct" intuition and the "solution" in your picture gives you to prove the result:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{1-\frac13\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n}{1+\frac13\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n}
=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[1-\frac13\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n\right]}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ 1+\frac13\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n\right]}=1
$$

Comment: Then, lets say that my sum is 

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N an
$$

The partial sum of this sumation is:
$$
\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}
$$

So, if I wanna evaluate the sum of the first n-th terms, I just use the formula:
$$
\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}
$$

Now, I wanna see if the summation diverges or converges. How would I do that?

Comment: @MatheusMinguini: Sorry, could you make your typing clearly? I can't read it if it is not typed correctly.

Comment: Yes, I did... is it better now?

Comment: @MatheusMinguini: I'm confused. When you say "the partial sum of this summation is $\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}$", do you really mean (I) $$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}$$ or (II) $$\sum_{n=1}^Na_n=\frac{5^N-3^{N-1}}{5^N+3^N}\ ?$$

Comment: For a **series** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, the finite sum $\sum_{n_1}^Na_n$ is called the **partial sum of** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. It does not makes sense to talk about the "partial sum" of  $\sum_{n=1}^Na_n$. Could you clarify what exactly is your case?

Comment: If your question is from an exercise of some book, it would be VERY useful if you could post the original problem in your post. It is very difficult to guess what your question really is.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for that. I posted the picture that contains the exercise origin. Answering your previous question, I strongly believe that is the second case (II)

Comment: I plotted the expression as a function (in case it helps): https://pt.symbolab.com/graphing-calculator?functions=%5Cfrac%7B5%5E%7Bn%7D-3%5E%7Bn-1%7D%7D%7B5%5E%7Bn%7D%2B3%5E%7Bn%7D%7D

Comment: @MatheusMinguini: thanks for that. See edits in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The $5^n$ terms dominate for $n$ large and the limit is $1$; to prove that, let's consider

$$\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}=\frac{1-\frac13\left(\frac35\right)^{n}}{1+\left(\frac35\right)^{n}}$$

and then take the limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood that we need to change the expression to something *equivalent*, but the core of my doubt is: Why does it work for one and not for the other? I mean, 2 + 2 = 4 and 3 + 1 = 4. They are both equivalent, they should give the same output

Comment: @MatheusMinguini $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is actually not defined because $\infty$ is not a number . We can not say that since the both the numerator and the denominator approaches $\infty$ , then the fraction also approaches $\infty.$

Comment: @MatheusMinguini The reason is in the definition of limit. When we say that the limit is $\infty$ we are referring to a precise definition which doesn't include the case $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{5^n-3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}=1-\frac{4\cdot 3^{n-1}}{5^n+3^n}\ge \frac12$$ so that the sum diverges.

Comment: Actually, it converges to 1

Comment: @MatheusMinguini: it is useless to evaluate the limit.